# Problemas de instalación de composer en Windows

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Estoy instalando `composer` para aprender `Laravel`, pero la instalación de `composer` no se finaliza y me muestra el siguiente error:

```
The Composer installer script was not successful [exit code 1].

Script Output:
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. 
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.
```

En la instalación yo no marqué el checkbox para usar proxy, no se si tendrá algo que ver con esto.
¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Trabajas detrás de un proxy?

Comment: Si, pero también tenemos un repositorio local en la universidad

Comment: Entonces si vas a descargar composer de un servidor local deberías indicar la ip

Comment: Intenta descargandolo de aqui https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe asegurate de tener instalado xampp, o algun entorno con php